# Suggested edit approved from the post itself still shows up in the /review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review

Unfortunately I don't have screenshots, but I just noticed this odd behaviour on the [Salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site.

I was looking at a flagged question and it had an edit pending, so I went ahead and approved it before handling the flag. After that, I went to look at the suggested edits queue, and the same edit that I already approved was still in there. (I hit "Approve" again, and no errors turned up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some earlier bugs that we resolved that should have included a fix for this.  Let us know if it happens again.